# dynamically include files using msbuild while preserving relative path?

Tags: msbuild, embedded-resource, csproj

I am trying to include files from a second project as EmbeddedResources using the following msbuild target:

```
    <CreateItem Include="..\MyProject.Templates\**\*.css">
      <Output ItemName="EmbeddedResource" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
```

but the included file loose their path e.g. `~\Views\_Layout.cshtml` is included as `_Layout.cshtml` (not `Views._Layout.cshtml` as is desired). Is there some way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The 'CreateItem' task is deprecated, are there any reasons for you to use it?

Comment: Copy n paste from http://ayende.com/blog/4446/how-to-setup-dynamic-groups-in-msbuild-without-visual-studio-ruining-them All I want to achieve is (1) bringing in embedded resources from a wildcard route, (2) in such a way VS doesn't materialize them out, (3) while preserving path structure. This manages (1) and (2)...

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild has [New Methods for Manipulating Items and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651786(v=vs.90).aspx). Using these methods, you can map your resources using an ItemGroup (instead of CreateItem), then create another ItemGroup applying [MSBuild Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476(v=vs.110).aspx) with [MSBuild Well-known Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx).  There are many item metadata options you could use to achieve the desired effect. There's a clear example of the syntax on [this answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090912102740/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770298/transform-itemgroup-msbuild-to-another-itemgroup-while-applying-formatting).

I wrote a little script as an example. It creates an ItemGroup with *.exe files and transforms them. Tested with MSBuild 3.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="CreateItems" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CreateItems">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Exe Include="..\**\*.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <TransformedExe Include="@(Exe->'%(Relativedir)')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="1 - @(Exe)" />
    <Message Text="2 - @(TransformedExe)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: So simple and so useful.  I wonder if this ever worked for the OP.  I just switched a project from NAnt to MSBuild, and I'm very impressed so far with how well thought-out it is.

Comment: your "[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770298/transform-itemgroup-msbuild-to-another-itemgroup-while-applying-formatting)" has been removed ... do you have new link for it? or ...?

Comment: @Seagal82 did my best finding a new link, dunno why they deleted the answer